# convert String to Date in android throws ParseException

Tags: java, android, date

Just don't know why this snippet is not correct.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
String nowDate1 = formatter.format(now.getTime());
Date nowDate = formatter.parse(nowDate1);
```

Comment: Does `formatter.parse("2012/11/05");` work?

Comment: nope, still same ParseException

Comment: Are you getting a ParseException at runtime or at compile time?

Comment: Federico, I have edit my question

Comment: no, it shows in the text Editor

Comment: is the `Date` imported from `java.util` and not `java.sql`?

Comment: It's a compile time exception.  Please read my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, your are not including the [try / catch sentences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html):

```
try {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); 
    String nowDate1 = formatter.format(now.getTime());
    Date nowDate = formatter.parse(nowDate1);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As *parse()* could throw a ***ParseException*** at runtime, the compiler is warning you about it, and that is why you need to consider the possibility of a ParseException.